# How to draw a UML Class\Interface hierarchy, identifying which nodes are classes and which are interfaces

Tags: flash

Task1: Movies
In a movie store application, you are asked to consider the following kinds of movies:

**Movie**, a class describing all kinds of movies.

**Action**, a movie containing lots of explosions.

**Romance**, a movie where romantic interest drives the plot

**Comedy**, a movie with largely humorous content

**Mystery**, a who - dunnit movie

**Rescue**, a hybrid action  - romance movie, where the main character attempts to save his or her romantic interest from almost certain doom.

**Romantic  Comedy**, a hybrid romance – comedy with large amounts of both humorous and romantic content.

**Hollywood Blockbuster**, an action – romance  - comedy – mystery movie designed to please crowds.

What interfaces and classes would you use to represent the previous list of movies? Write your answer by carefully drawing a UML class/interface hierarchy, identifying which nodes are classes and which are interfaces. Note that there must be a class for each type of the movies, but you may use any interfaces you require to preserve the relationships between types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulting UML structure for your task can look like on the diagram below.
There are two possible ways to do it.

1. Define Movie class with attribute named category. Category is enumeration type. Any instance of move belongs to some category.
2. Use abstract Movie class and created specialization structure. Specialized types of movies are classes. Define generalization set for this tree. All specialized types are generalized by category type.

I do not think that there are interfaces. I afraid interface does nothing to do with relationship preservation.

[image]